# CakePHP: Single Post Per Day based on IP Address

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, ip

I'm still getting the hang of CakePHP but I think I'm making progress.

Background: I'm developing an application that doesn't require registration. I essentially have posts that can be made by any visitor to the site.

Question: How can I limit the number of times a guest can post per day? Say I want to allow a guest to post once per day. Would I essentially create a users table based on IP, log a new IP address every time one visits the site, then limit actions based on that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create a .txt file that stores the IP of a user, with PHP's `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. After 24 hours, at 12:00, have your webserver wipe the IP file, enabling everybody to post again for the next day.

Comment: That sounds like an elegant solution. Plus avoids the database! Thanks for your response :)

Comment: @div No problem- I'm not a fan of MySQL either :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes...that would do it but I wouldn't recommend it. A user can change their IP by using a proxy or just reconnecting to their ISP. So ..basically I wouldn't use IP based filtering if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you want to have users + guest or just guest.

If you have users (logged to the site, with profile and everything a normal user will get) and also allow guess to post, then it's easier to add a guest + ip (or another filtering option) to the users table and associate it with the post table by an user_id column in the post table (kind of what is done here in SO).

But, if there's only guest in the site and it's not intended to have logged users, then you just need a post table with an ip column where you can register which ip did the post.

Also, as Iansen said, the IP filter can be easily bypassed. Is it a strong requisite that the user only post once per day?

Comment: I think using the IP filtering would cut out enough posts. We only have guests and no users, and it's not horribly critical for the restriction to work in every case. And thank you for your response!